Strip all column values, but check if any tuples exist
I have multiple dataframes that use the same functions to strip all the values. However, some of the values are tuples and it is throwing an error whenever I come across stripping a tuple.
My function looks like this:
for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].dtype == 'object':   
            df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: str(x).strip())

I have another function for a specific dataframe that will always have tuples:
for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].dtype == 'object':   
            df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: str(x).strip())

    df['Commodity'] = [(x.strip() for x in ls) for ls in df['Commodity'].values]
    df['Commodity'] = df['Commodity'].apply(sorted)

The second function will always throw an error when it gets to the Commodity column because it will not handle the tuples. How can I handle that specific case in the first function?

What about something like:
for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].dtype == 'object':   
            df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: str(x).strip() if isinstance(x, str)
                                              else (s.strip() for s in x))

Or with a custom recursive function:
def cust_strip(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return x.strip()
    if isinstance(x, tuple):
        return tuple(cust_strip(item) for item in x)
    return x

for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].dtype == 'object':   
            df[col] = df[col].apply(cust_strip)

Example:
# input
df = pd.DataFrame({'str': [' abc ', 'def '],
                   'tuple': [(' ghi', ' jkl '), ('mno ',)]})

# output:
out = pd.DataFrame({'str': ['abc', 'def'],
                    'tuple': [('ghi', 'jkl'), ('mno',)]})

